# Big M Method- magnitude of M

Tags: optimization, linear-programming

In the Big M Method used to solve a linear programming problem, how large is M meant to be? What is meant by "very large"?

Comment: Large enough so that the artificial variable(s) would not be part of any feasible solution - of course, this depends on the problem in question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The value M is *defined* as being large enough so that any number involving it is absolutely larger than any number not doing so. This means that artificial variables are forced out of the infeasible basis one at a time, and what remains is a feasible one, ready to start normal iteration.